# Onchange of selection how to fix the size of another text field

Tags: javascript, php, html

These are required

1. Passport
2. Driving license
3. aadhar card (as selection options)

When I select passport, the another text field should correspondingly change to corresponding pattern of passport and so on.

What would be the better options to do this ?

I saw `onchange` event but I'm not that familiar with JavaScript so I need some suggestions.

Comment: onchange event can do this to you , when onchange is called then you can put your text like you want in any object in the DOM :)

Comment: I even want to limit the pattern for particular selection

Comment: explain more please :)

Comment: Yeah, when i select on passport from drop down , the input field as text to be change to unique pattern acceptance like wise when i select on driving licence the input field to be change to unique pattern acceptance

Comment: do not change the input field.. generate different input fields for different purpose.. it will be easier to manage...

Comment: Yeah that would go well .But requirement is like to reuse same input field for different selection:(

Comment: @ahalya can you show some example of inputs?? I mean which type of inputs with which attributes do you want?

Comment: if selection is aadhaar no : the input text field should be limited to "xxxx xxxx xxxx" this pattern

Comment: As @NishantSolanki mentioned, it's better for you to create different input fields and hide them and only show the one regarding to which one is supposed to be shown. in this way, you can define exact pattern for each field. if you need more help, please share with us what you have done till now(I mean your code)